# Spotify DJ button: any way to click it from the CLI (or AppleScript, or Hammerspoon, or...)

Tags: spotify, hammerspoon

Is there any way to simulate clicking the Spotify DJ button in the macOS Spotify application from outside Spotify, for example with a keypress?

[image: Spotify's DJ button]

Of course, I could just bring up the Spotify window and go click it. But I regularly use Hammerspoon to automate many other tasks like window manipulation, so it'd be nice to just be able to just hit a global key binding (say, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⏩</kbd>) to let the DJ know to move onto the next set, without further interrupting whatever I'm working on.

Some ideas I looked into:

- [Spotify's AppleScript API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8901556/296829): I don't see a way to hit that DJ button. (You can view it with the `Script Editor` app, File -> Open Dictionary, Spotify).
- [Hammerspon's hs.spotify](https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.spotify.html): awesome, but [under the hood just uses AppleScript](https://github.com/Hammerspoon/hammerspoon/blob/master/extensions/spotify/spotify.lua)
- Checking for something in the Menu bar I could click on with [hs.application:selectMenuItem()](https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.application.html#selectMenuItem), no relevant menu bar items I could find
- Some other resources, like CLI tools, Node.js programs, etc, the ones I found were just wrappers for AppleScript
- Right clicking the Dock icon; Next/Previous but no option for the DJ button
- [libspotify](https://developer.spotify.com/blog/2022-04-12-libspotify-sunset): sunsetted, doubt it supports the recent DJ feature
- [Spotify's Web Playback SDK Reference](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/reference#spotifyplayer) and [Spotify's Web API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api): would require writing an app, using Oauth, etc—I'd be willing, and I was able to get playlist info about the DJ, but I didn't see anything that does what that DJ button does
- One not-so-great idea might simply be to simply skip 5 tracks

Thanks.